# Bootstrap navbar not showing items correctly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently trying to learn Bootstrap, but i've run into a problem. The navbar is not show its items like it should when it is in the mobile view.

First her is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Test Bootstrap!</title>
                <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scal=1.0'>
                <link href='css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
                <link href='css/styles.css' rel='stylesheet'>
            </head>

            <body>
               <div class='navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top' role='navigation'>
                    <div class='container'>

                        <a href= '#' class='navbar-brand'>BootstrapTest</a>

                        <button class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navHeaderCollapse'>
                            <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                            <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                            <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                        </button>


                        <div class='collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse'>
                            <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
                                <li class='active'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#'>Something</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
                <script src='js/bootstrap.js'></script>
            </body>
        </html>
```

And here is how it looks when the toggle button is pressed:
[image]

I really can't figure out what i'm doing wrong so I hope someone else could spot the problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: is there any particular reason why your navbar div is placed outside of the parent <div class="container"> container? Where is the navbar-header class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're missing is the `navbar-header` element:

```
<body>
  <div class='navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top' role='navigation'>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href= '#' class='navbar-brand'>BootstrapTest</a>
        <button class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navHeaderCollapse'>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        </button>
      </div>
     ...
```

Bootstrap (just as everything new at the first time we try it) can be a little confusing. Try to take a moment to read through their website, and take a look especially at their [examples section](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples), you can always see how they do things, and take the code samples as first guidance.

That's going to allow you to familiarize not only with the framework, but also with some of the basic "best practices".

Comment: You can take a look and play around with this here: http://jsbin.com/tejivoxopa/edit?html,output

Comment: @Imdrx Thank you for your help! I was following a tutoral on youtube, where his example worked, but he is NOT using the navbar-header.. I guess I won't be following his tutorials anymore :) I will look at the website of bootstrap instead like you suggested instead. +1 and accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding the navbar-header, you'll need to move the navbar-collapse class outside of the navbar header class.  Here's a working version.  (FYI:  I also moved the script link into the header.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Bootstrap!</title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scal=1.0'>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class='navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top' role='navigation'>
          <div class='container'>
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a href= '#' class='navbar-brand'>BootstrapTest</a>

              <button class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navHeaderCollapse'>
                  <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                  <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                  <span class='icon-bar'></span>
              </button>

            </div>

            <div class='collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse'>
                <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
                    <li class='active'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Something</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

          </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```